# Как при наведении на что-либо заставить появится блок?

Tags: html, css

Точно знаю, что с помощью css можно так сделать, но как?

```
a:hover -> ..
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как-то так:

```css
.content{ /* Скрываем сразу контент */
  display: none;
}
.wrapper a:hover ~ .content{ /* При наведении на ссылку в раппере, откроется контент */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <a href='#'>Да, да, на меня наведи</a>
  <div class='content'>Я скрытый контент</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А "~" нужно? или можно без?

Comment: @goodalien1125, в данном случае - нужно, просто помещать весь контент в ссылку - это семантически глупо. Поэтому используем селектор отбора соседа (можно и `+`, но тут особо не так уж важно).

Comment: Точно! Совсем забыл про родственные селекторы. Спасибо, что напомнили)).

Comment: @Astor, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  }

a:hover div {
  height: 300px;
  )
```

```html
<a href="#">Наведи на меня
<div></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так  тоже можно - мои 5 копеек

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.first{
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
 background:yellow;
 margin:20px auto;
 position:relative;
 border-radius:6px;
 line-height:50px;
}
.first:hover{
 border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;
}
.first>p{
 padding-left:20px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:blue;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.first .parent{
 position:absolute;
 top:20px; left:0;
 width:300px;
 height:0;
 line-height:1px;
 border-left:2px solid yellow;
 border-right:2px solid yellow;
 border-bottom:2px solid yellow;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
 transition-duration:1s;
 transition-delay:1s;
 padding:10px;
}
.first .parent img{
 display:block;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 transition:all 1s;
 transition-duration:1s;
 transition-delay:1s;
}
.first:hover .parent img{
 float:left;
 width:45%;
 height:auto;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-bottom:-5px;
}
.first .parent p{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:10px 5px;
 text-align:justify;
 font-size:0;
 transition-duration:1s;
 transition-delay:1s;
 color:#fff;
}
.first:hover .parent{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px; left:0;
 width:300px;
 min-height:390px;
 line-height:16px;
 border-left:2px solid yellow;
 border-right:2px solid yellow;
 border-bottom:2px solid yellow;
 box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}
.first:hover .parent p{
 display:block;
 width:90%;
 margin:10px auto;
 text-align:justify;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#000;
}
```

```html
 <div class="first"> 
   <p>Наведи на меня</p>
  <div class="parent">
      <img src="http://ladysovety.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/kakoj-syurpriz-sdelat-muzhu-na-godovshhinu-svadby-300x267.jpg" alt="image" />  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Мм, какая картинка)